# flutter page transition - create effect for page 2 sliding in and page 1 sliding out

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I haven't been able to find any good documentation online for this.
When creating a page transition, e.g. slide Page 2 into the screen (over Page 1), is there a way to add an effect which appears to slide Page 1 out?
So as Page 2 is sliding in, Page 1 is sliding out.
Currently all examples I've seen only overlay the Page2 transition animation over Page1.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't think to use a PageView, I will try that!

Comment: ohh, so you meant route transition? then see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation and https://medium.com/flutter-community/page-transitions-using-themedata-in-flutter-c24afadb0b5d, the second link better explains how to use it with `PageTransitionsTheme`

Comment: Sorry, yes i meant route transition. I have used the first example in the past, but in that example the second page animates "over" the first page. What I would like is to create an effect which simultaneously slides page 2 onto the screen and also slides page 1 out, so it looks like page 2 is pushing page 1. So far I can only think of PageView achieving this effect.

Comment: i wolud do that by using `PageTransitionsTheme` - it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: Thanks, I will do some research, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I use named routes to achieve sliding when navigation occurs, with **[onGenerateRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateRoute.html)** and a custom **[PageRouteBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageRouteBuilder-class.html)**. Not my idea, I took it from somewhere but it works fine. Code looks like this:

```
return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'MyApp',
   onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
     switch (settings.name) {
       case '/':
         return SlideRoute(page: Home(), settings: settings);
       case '/route1':
         return SlideRoute(page: Route1(), settings: settings);
       case '/route2':
         return SlideRoute(page: Route2(), settings: settings);
        }
      },
   );

class SlideRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  final RouteSettings settings;
  SlideRoute({required this.page, required this.settings})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              page,
          settings: settings,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(1, 0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
   }
```

And then you navigate to a named route like this:

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/route1');
```

In `settings` you can also pass arguments to named routes, if you like, [see here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

In the below package you can achieve slide in/out transition

https://github.com/handoing/flutter_page_transition

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this package has low scores and does not support sound null safety.